# Command "Print All Lines Starting With"

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk, command

I am looking for a perl command where lines starting with a string are printed. For example, if I wanted to print all lines starting with "1234", what would that command look like? Sed? Awk? Grep?

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -ne 'print if /^1234/'
```

or

```
sed -ne '/^1234/p'
```

or

```
awk '/^1234/'
```

or

```
grep '^1234'
```

or

```
ruby -ne 'print if /^1234/'
```

or even

```
python -c 'import fileinput;print "\n".join([l for l in fileinput.input() if l.startswith("1234")])'
```

Comment: oh, python is so-o-o-o beautiful

Comment: `python -c 'import sys; [sys.stdout.write(l) for l in sys.stdin if l.startswith("1234")]'` -- maybe slightly less pathological, but clearly Python is not meant to replace grep  :)

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, @Eevee.  Of course using sys.stdin doesn't let you specify a list of files at the end of the command line the way the rest of the entries in my answer do... :)  But yes, this is definitely not Python's niche.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne'print if /^1234/' file
```

But most people would use `grep`.

```
grep ^1234 file
```

Or on Windows

```
findstr /r ^1234 file
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion:

```
sed -ne '/^1234/p' somefile
awk '/^1234/{print}' somefile
grep '^1234' somefile
```

Comment: `{print}` is the default action for awk, so you all you need is the `/^1234/` part.