# Print whole line that begins with specific pattern

Tags: perl

I have a text file that looks like this http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?sort=score&desc=&compress=no&query=id:P01375%20OR%20id:P04626%20OR%20id:P08238%20OR%20id:P06213&format=txt

I have to print only the lines in the text file that start with specific pattern (ID).

I tried it this way but it doesn't working:

```
open (IDS, 'example.txt') or die "Cannot open";    
my @ids = <IDS>;    
close IDS;    
my @IDS= "ID";    
foreach my $ids (@ids) {    
  if (my @ids =~ my @IDS){    
    print $ids;    
  } 
}
```

There probably must be some problem in this line **if (my @ids =~ my @IDS){.

If somebody can help me I would be very thankful.

Best

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569570/command-print-all-lines-starting-with

Comment: Thank You very much for this answer, but I have to write a script in Perl instead of using command in terminal. Can You see what' wrong in the script that I wrote?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long list list of comments, here you go! This snippet works for both of your cases!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $input, '<', 'printLinesStartingWithID.txt' ) or die $!; 
while ( <$input> ) { 
   if(/^ID/)
   {
        print "Matched line starting with ID: $_";
   }
   if(/^AC/)
   {
        my ($secondCol) = $_ =~ /^AC...(.*?)\;/;    #The three dots is to chop off the three empty spaces followed by 'AC'.
        print "Matched line starting with AC. The second column of the line is: $secondCol \n";
   }
}
close ( $input );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is almost certainly this line:

```
  if (my @ids =~ my @IDS){
```

because `my` is declaring a new variable, that 'hides' the one in the parent scope. Applying a regex match when both source and target are arrays is also going to behave in an odd sort of way - you're iterating `@ids` one element at a time, but then you're just matching the whole thing. And you're matching against another array, which ... actually works, but only because you're relying on casting the array to a string and back again.

It's also pretty bad style to have upper case and lower case variables of the same name, and you're doing it 3 times with `@ids`, `@IDS`, and `IDS`.

I'm also really not sure that `my @IDS = "ID";` is doing what you think it's doing, and neither is trying to treat `@IDS` as a pattern in the first place.

Also - reading a file into an array then iterating it is less efficient that just iterating the file line by line.

Your code could probably be simplified as:

```
open ( my $input, '<', 'example.txt' ) or die $!; 
while ( <$input> ) { 
   print if m/ID/;
}
close ( $input );
```

Comment: Dear Sobrique, Thank You for spending Your time. I have never used Perl before, niether some other programming language, so I don't have any experience. I don't understand one thing. My $input should be a filehendler; and when I type, for example id, the output of this simple script is not what I am searching for, it does not prints me anly lines that are beginning with the pattern /ID/. What I have to do is from a file that looks like link I have attached to print out only lines (whole lines) that begin with ID and lines that begin with AC (but not whole line, only first column). Thanks!

Comment: That would be a different question. I'd suggest you ask it as such.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thank You once again!

Comment: @sergio: You asked a second question, but you included your original (very broken!) code from this question. Let's get this fixed first, and only move on to the next stage when you understand this code. What don't you understand?

Comment: @Dave Cross: Thanks Dave. I agree. So, as I said before, what I don't understand is the role of file handle my $input. By reading different examples I see that it is a file handle and that by  writing "<" my file will be only read (not opening it in a writing mode, ">"). I understood that file handle is just mentioning the way I want my file to be read (an undefined scalar variable), so I can put anything there (maybe I didn't understand it well). I used this script and changed $input to $ids. Therefore, obviously I have a problem with understanding this file handle.

Comment: @sergio: Sounds like you understand it well enough. Why do you think you don't understand it? Did something not work? What unexpected behaviour did you see? Were there any error messages?

Comment: @Dave Cross: Well I think I don't understand it because, when I change all $input with $ids and when I run the script as an output I was given a randomly printed data and I don't know why, it seems to be simple and straightforward.

Comment: @sergio: Without seeing the changes, it's impossible for me to know what is going wrong. If you want more help, edit your question to include your latest code and some sample input.

Comment: @Sobrique Did you just write a snippet for printing all lines that has `ID` in it?!

Comment: @Sobrique your snippet prints all lines that has ID anywhere in it. But the question was pretty clear that the pattern should be in the start of the line. I think you need to modify your regex to this. `print if m/^ID/ || m/^AC/;`

Comment: @Bala: Yes that is the problem that I had. All lines that contain ID were printed. With adding ^ I got only those that are beginning with this specific /pattern/. Do You know what should I add to ^AC, to make only second column printed, or at least some kind of a hint, because I can not find that somebody else did something similar in previous questions.

Comment: what do you mean by second column while printing lines starting with AC ? What exactly do you need from this line - `AC   P01375; O43647; Q9P1Q2; Q9UIV3;`

Comment: @sergio You can maybe open a new question for this because in future, it may help somebody.

Comment: @Bala: I've already opened new question for this which can be found in this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390656/printing-only-those-lines-with-a-specific-pattern-idac-and-only-first-column-o). Yes, I understand that there are no colums but I meant P01375. Thanks!